# While wrapping C++ code with python using SWIG, is it safe to pass additional compiler flags which optimize and parallelize code?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using disutils to generate python modules. These are the additional flags I'm passing:

```
tradelogic_module = Extension(...
                               extra_compile_args = ["/Ot", "/O2", "/Qpar"],
                       )
```

Here,

`/O2` and `/Ot` optimize the code for speed and `/Qpar` generates parallel code (if possible, at all)

distutils docs say that distutils prefers compiling everything with same flags and passes flags which were used while building python.

Are errors likely while using module compiled like this?

Edit: I'm using Windows, by the way. But same question applies to linux too (with different flags, of course).

Comment: Is this for Windows?

Comment: @tadman Yes, Win 10.

Comment: If optimization flags change the observable behaviour of your code, then your code likely contains bugs (in the form of Undefined Behaviour).

Comment: @JesperJuhl They don't. I'm asking about SWIG generated wrappers.

Comment: Using option that control only those aspects of the compilation should be OK as long as they don't cause link errors.